# Calculate standard deviation from band-limited white noise

Tags: matlab, simulink, noise, standard-deviation

I have a [Band-Limited White Noise](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/bandlimitedwhitenoise.html) block with a given *Noise Power*. What is the mathematic equation between this Noise power and the standard deviation of the signal?

I could use the *std* function in Matlab to calculate the standard deviation but there must be a equation based correlation like:

[image: sigma = ? * S]

Could anybody help me out there?

Edit 1: Example.

I have: The Noise power and sample time.
I want: Standard deviation via an equation
[image]

Comment: Square root of the power of the Noise should be correct (given that there are no other catches). Also might interest you is that if you divide your signal by the standard deviation, you should get the normalized signal

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I added an example. With sqrt(1) I got 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, thank you. You were right. I didn´t see it.

The answer is:

sqrt(Noise Power / Sample Time)